# Get text of the selected option with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

I have a select box with some values. How do I get the selected options text, not the value?

```
<select name="options[2]" id="select_2">
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="6" price="0">100</option>
    <option value="7" price="0">125</option>
    <option value="8" price="0">150</option>
    <option value="9" price="0">175</option>
    <option value="10" price="0">200</option>
    <option value="3" price="0">25</option>
    <option value="4" price="0">50</option>
    <option value="5" price="0">75</option>
</select>
```

I tried this:

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j("select#select_2").change(function(){
        val = $j("select#select_2:selected").text();
        alert(val);
    });
});
```

But it's coming back with `undefined`.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Close, you can use

```
$('#select_2 option:selected').html()
```

Comment: Will $('#select_2 :selected').html() also works?

Comment: @JoseFaeti apparently, yes : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/kcWQw/7/

Comment: Keep in mind that $('#select_2').find('option:selected').html() will be more efficient ;).

Comment: @Archangel Out of curiosity, in what way will that be more efficient?

Comment: @Damian It will first narrow the search drastically with the id selector and then find the selected option. It might be the same thing in this particular case but it's a good reflex to have in other ones.

Comment: @Archangel Fair enough, it's just your original comment sounded like it would be a more efficient for this example, which if it is would be negligible at best as they essentially do the same thing. Using `.find()` can be beneficial (like in a scenario I had earlier today) but from my experience it's more of a circumstantial method to use as it's rare that I need to use it as there are usually better ways.

Comment: @Damian I agree with you. Actually I should have specify that it would be "usually" more efficient but not always.

Comment: @Archangel yup that solved my problem too, find() gives us only selected Html/text of given id where the posted solution gives all the Html/text associated with that id.

Comment: @B-shan Only replying to this because of the confusing downvote. The posted solution works just fine and only returns the HTML of the selected option, not all HTML associated with that ID (as you mention). This fiddle is evidence of it - http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/kcWQw/7/  . User Archangel's comment doesn't change anything in the solution as it's functionally the same solution.

Comment: @JohnP that was by mistake I tried to undo it but it's saying answer needs to be edited as the vote is locked, sorry for the inconvenience that wasn't intentional.

Comment: @B-shan That's alright then

Answer (score 27):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select#select_2').change(function() {
        var selectedText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        alert(selectedText);
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLP8p/)**

Comment: this is the most elegant one...especially when you have the select as an object

Comment: When you've assigned your select to a variable, e.g. `foo = $('#select2)` this is the variation to use, as in

`foo.find('option:selected').text()`

Answer (score 13):

Change your selector to

```
val = j$("#select_2 option:selected").text();
```

You're selecting the `<select>` instead of the `<option>`

Answer (score 4):

Also u can consider this

```
$('#select_2').find('option:selected').text();
```

which might be a little faster solution though I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could actually put the value = to the text and then do

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j("select#select_2").change(function(){
        val = $j("#select_2 option:selected").html();
        alert(val);
    });
});
```

Or what I did on a similar case was

```
<select name="options[2]" id="select_2" onChange="JavascriptMethod()">
  with you're options here
</select>
```

With this second option you should have a undefined.
Give me feedback if it worked :)

Patrick