# Don't know how to make this with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Hey I have a little issue with jQuery

I want to have information from the select

 I don't know how i can do this in jQuery so i did a other thing but the teacher said me to change this

```
<select class="submit-status"
                            onchange="changeStatusAdmin(jQuery(this))" 
                            name="statusOption" id="status-option">
                        <?php
                        //Liste deroulante pour les statuts
                        foreach($allStatus as $status){
                            $statusName = utf8_encode($status->getStatus());
                            if($status->getId() 
                                    == $suggestion->getStatusId()){
                                $statusSelected = "selected = selected";
                            } 
                            else{
                                $statusSelected = '';
                            }?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $status->getId();?>"
                                <?php echo $statusSelected; ?>>
                                <?php echo $statusName; ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
```

I want to get the variable $statusName in jQuery but i can't change the value 

 And here is my jQuery code

```
var status = item.parents(".idea-meta").find(".submit-status").val()
if(status == 2){
                status = "En attente";
            }
            if(status == 3){
                status = "Refusée";
            }
            if(status == 4){
                status = "Débutée";
            }
            if(status == 5){
                status = "Planifiée";
            }
            if(status == 6){
                status = "Terminée";
            }
```

Sry for my bad english and thanks in advance

Comment: What's the problem exactly? I couldn't understand

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6454073/505722

Comment: I want to get the variable $statusName with the jQuery status

Comment: Can you please replace your php by the outputted HTML ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution. But it's a duplicate question.

*Voilà une solution à ton problème. L'utilisation de onchange directement dans le DOM est une mauvaise pratique qu'il faut éviter au maximum. Si ça t'aide hésite pas à valider la réponse ;)*

Bon courage !

```
<select class="submit-status" name="statusOption" id="status-option">
<?php
    //Liste deroulante pour les statuts
    foreach($allStatus as $status){
        $statusName = utf8_encode($status->getStatus());

        if($status->getId() == $suggestion->getStatusId())
            $statusSelected = "selected = selected";
        else
            $statusSelected = '';
    ?>
        <option value="<?= $status->getId(); ?>" <?= $statusSelected; ?>>
            <?php echo $statusName; ?>
        </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $("#status-option").change(function(){
        var contenu = $("#status-option option:selected").text();
        console.log(contenu); // affichage dans la console du contenu
    });
</script>
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85k9hb8m/)