# get select text with jquery in table

Tags: jquery-clone

i have a table with this select:

```
<tr class="tr_clone">
    <td>
      <select style="width:200px" name="itens[]" class="itemname">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Item A</option>
        <option value="2">Item B</option>
        <option value="3">Item C</option>
    </td>
```

in jquery, I am trying to get the text of the selected item (Item A when 1 is selected). I am then putting this value to another text box, (named 'note'). I can put the index value but not the text of the select.

```
$("table").on('change', '.itemname', function() { 
   var prtCont = $(this).parent().parent();
    var code =  prtCont.find('.itemname').val();
  prtCont.find('.note').val(code);
});
```

what should I change in my jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 1st close the select tag.

```
<tr class="tr_clone">
<td>
  <select style="width:200px" name="itens[]" class="itemname">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Item A</option>
    <option value="2">Item B</option>
    <option value="3">Item C</option>
  </select>
</td> 
</tr>
```

To get the text of the [selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6454073) you can do:

```
$('.itemname option:selected').html()
```

Your jQuery is a little confuse, for me is better:

```
$('.itemname').on('change' , function() {
  var prtCont = $(this).parent().parent(); 
   code = $(this).val();  // Get the value
   text = $('.itemname option:selected').html(); // Get the text
   prtCont.find('.note').val(code + '   ' +text);
});
```